# How to use Expression Template with appSettings in Serilog

Tags: c#, configuration, serilog

I've a file sink configured in the `appsettings.json` of my application.
 It works perfectly but now I want to add an expression template to format the output in my file.
 As I can see, there's no way to set expression template using configuration files.
 If this is not possible, is there a way to use inline configuration for my file sink but to keep the file path into the configuration file ?

Thanks

Comment: If this is what you mean by expression template, there is an example [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#nested-configuration-sections)

Comment: No, this is a output template. I look for an expression template as described there : https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions.

Comment: Got it. But I'm still not clear what you are asking since the link you posted has examples of expressions in the json config file.

Comment: The examples are there for filters and other things but not as sink formatter

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**As of version 3.3.0** of *Serilog.Settings.Configuration*, this is now possible:

```json
{
  "Name": "Console",
  "Args": {
    "formatter": {
      "type": "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions",
      "template": "[{@t:HH:mm:ss} {@l:u3} {Coalesce(SourceContext, '<none>')}] {@m}\n{@x}"
    }
  }
}
```

**For earlier versions** there's no direct support, but if you put the template into a static property somewhere:

```cs
public static class Formatters
{
    public static ITextFormatter Output { get; } = new ExpressionTemplate(...);
}
```

Then you can pass that value through JSON configuration by naming the static property:

```
{
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": { "formatter"" "YourApp.Formatters::Output, YourApp" }
}
```

(Check the arguments accepted by the sink to see what the name of the formatter argument is - but it should be `formatter` as above in most cases.)

Comment: Has anyone submitted a feature request to support this?  It would make sense since you can already use the `expression=` syntax with filters in `appsettings.json`.

Comment: @ZachBlocker none I'm aware of, but even an issue with a design proposal would be really welcome over at the _Serilog.Settings.Configuration_ repo 

Comment: @ZachBlocker still no news? I am looking for the same feature, but still can't find anything

Comment: @maradev21 yes, there's been some progress  - the syntax is shown in: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/pull/281, but you'll need to install the `3.3.0-dev-00291` or later version of Serilog.Settings.Configuration from NuGet

Comment: How do you specify the theme? I've tried this but I can't get it to work

`"theme": "Serilog.Templates.Themes.TemplateTheme::Code"`

Comment: @Ryan it is now possible with Serilog.Settings.Configuration v3.4.0, assuming you add the assembly name (https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/287)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this doesn't seem to work with conditional blocks. `{#if @l = 'Error'}...{#end}` always gets spit out with my output :/