# Serilog Expression Template in appSettings.json is being ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, serilog

I am new to Serilog and am trying to use the Expression Template syntax within my `appSettings.Development.json` file.

In my `Program.cs` class I initialise the bootstrap logger from code. This works as expected, logging to the console with a 'normal' output template. Inside the `Startup.cs` class I re-setup the logger with `ReadFrom.Configuration(...).CreateLogger()`.

If my configuration looks as follows, it works correctly and logs to the console using the specified outputTemplate:

```
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {EnvironmentName:u3} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Resource}{NewLine}{Exception}",
      "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
    }
  },...]
```

The Serilog "using" tag, common to the configuration, is:

```
"Using": [
  "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
  "Serilog.Sinks.Seq",
  "Serilog.Expressions"
],
```

If I change the `WriteTo` tag to be as follows the log format is not honoured and the default template is used (the template configured with the bootstrap logger in fact):

```
 "WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
      "formatter": {
        "type": "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions",
        "template": "[{@t:HH:mm:ss} {@l:u3}{#if SourceContext is not null} ({SourceContext}){#end}] {@m}\n{@x}"
      }
    }
  },...]
```

In trying to work out the solution I have looked at the question posed by mberube.net [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66550450/how-to-use-expression-template-with-appsettings-in-serilog) but copying and pasting the code provided in that solution still doesn't log using the template format. My research to date indicates that the versions of the relevant Serilog packages I am using should be correct to enable this functionality.

My application is an ASP .Net Core Web API targetting `net5.0`. I have referenced `Serilog.Expressions Version="3.4.0"` and `Serilog.Settings.Configuration Version="3.3.0"`.

I am hoping someone can assist me to understand why the templated output format is not being applied and what I can do to correct it?

If there is any further information that is required please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The blocks in `appsettings.Development.json` files don't *override* the ones in `appsettings.json` - they're *merged in*, so what you're most likely ending up with is:

```json
 "WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Console",
    "Args": {
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} {EnvironmentName:u3} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Resource}{NewLine}{Exception}",
      "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "formatter": {
        "type": "Serilog.Templates.ExpressionTemplate, Serilog.Expressions",
        "template": "[{@t:HH:mm:ss} {@l:u3}{#if SourceContext is not null} ({SourceContext}){#end}] {@m}\n{@x}"
      }
    }
  }
```

This won't play well with Serilog's configuration overload selection - it'll pick what it thinks is the simplest option among possible configuration methods.

A better idea is to have no sink configuration ("WriteTo" blocks) in the root `appsettings.json` file at all, and put separate configurations in `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.Production.json`. It's very hard not to end up with unexpected results, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. Removing the sink configuration from the root ```appsettings.json``` file and having them only in the "environment" setting files has resolved the issue even though the root file did not contain a console sink (just a file sink). I look forward to exploring the power of expressions!